# ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API throws error 405 when trying to delete record using HttpDelete

Tags: c#, request, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0, http-method

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API application as I mentioned in the title I have an issue when trying to delete a record from the database; I'm getting an error `405 Method Not Allowed` response from `HttpDelete` request.

PS: I have added `services.AddCors()` and `app.UseCors()` with default policy.

This is the delete method code

```
public bool deleteLivreById(int id)
{
    Livre l = _db.Livres.Find(id);
    _db.Livres.Remove(l);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

And this is the `HttpDelete` method inside the controller

```
[HttpDelete("{id}/delete")]
   public bool deleteLivreById(int id)
      {
        return  _objGererLivre.deleteLivreById(id);
      }
```

Finally this is a picture from console when navigating to `HttpDelete` Url

[image]

Edit: This is full code of my controller

```
namespace GestionLivre.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("test")]
    public class LivreController : Controller
    {
        private IGererLivre _objGererLivre;
        public LivreController(IGererLivre gererLivre)
        {
            _objGererLivre = gererLivre;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult getLivres()
        {
            return Json(_objGererLivre.getLivres());
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}/delete")]
            public bool deleteLivreById(int id)
        {
               return  _objGererLivre.deleteLivreById(id);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show your controller route?

Comment: Also you probably should add [FromRoute] attribute for :

`public bool getById([FromRoute]int id)`

Comment: I just edited the post and added full controller code also i have tried to add [FromRoue] but still got the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand by default when you're trying to access URL in browser it uses GET method. So we should to pass in header appropriate method(POST,GET,DELETE,PATCH,PUT) If you want to test HTTP methods I'll recommend you to use Postman or Swagger. Postman much easier to use whether than Swagger which you should to add to service configuration and middleware.
Example of Postman:
[image]

And than configure body like that to return response.
[image]

Also recommend you to use REST Best Practices. And name resources properly. [https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/#:~:text=2.-,Best%20Practices,-2.1.%20Use%20nouns](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/#:%7E:text=2.-,Best%20Practices,-2.1.%20Use%20nouns)

Answer (score 3):

I opened the screenshot and noticed that you have selected 'GET' as http verb and method type is 'Delete'. Could you please change that and try.

Comment: I noticed that but i didn't really know how to change the header request 'GET' while the controller i'm giving a 'HttpDelete'. If you could point me on how to change it